# A propriedade 'map' não existe no tipo 'Observable <Response>'

Tags: javascript, angular

Estou usando a versão 6 do Angular e encontrei um erro na hora de usar o Observable. Ele diz q a propriedade map não existe no tipo Observable.
meu código está tipo isso.

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

         extratossaldo():Observable<Extratos[]> {
        return this.http.get(`${MEAT_API}/extratos`)
            .map(response => response.json());
}
```

Comment: qual versão do rxjs vc esta usando?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A partir da versão 5.5 do rxjs a forma correta de usar operadores e a seguinte:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators/map';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';  <!-- Angular 6 -->


extratossaldo():Observable<Extratos[]> {
    return this.http.get(`${MEAT_API}/extratos`).pipe(
        map(response => response.json()));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Valeu Eduardo Vargas. Deu certo, a única coisa q eu mudei foi os imports do map e do observable. Fiz assim ... 
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/internal/Observable';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';